# Improper href in display tag table:Pointing to wrong location

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, displaytag

I have below display table

```
<display:table name="jobTrackerCol" pagesize="20" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist">

<display:column title="File Link" sortable="true" property="ftp_link" href="${data.ftp_link}">

</display:table>
```

I am able to display the link properly but it is pointing to wrong location

e.g.
Below is my ftp link

```
 ftp://10.155.6.225/Velocity/1008.zip  ---should point to 1008.zip


    ftp://10.155.6.225/Velocity/1009.zip   -------should point to 1009.zip
```

All links are pointing to 1007.zip

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its working with this.

```
<display:column title="File Link" sortable="true" >
            <a href="${data.ftp_link}">${data.ftp_link}</a>

            </display:column>
```